# Application level caching in AEM

Tags: caching, aem

We are working on a site in AEM 6.1 which has news and events content with most pages having info on recent and related news/events based on tagging that are dynamic. We are using dispatcher. Please suggest on some caching techniques that could be implemented at application level apart from the dispatcher. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aim of implementing the caching on dispatcher is to allow less hits on your app server and serve as much as possible from web server. In short improving response time from your app server. But in some cases we can't cache too much on web server if results change on app server frequently.

On app server we can have following solutions implemented to get results quickly on top of having dispatcher in place.

1. Make sure your content hierarchy where you are ingesting news items have as less number of article as possible. Divide your hierarchy based on following structure. Year >> Month >> Day >> Hour (this can be ignored if content flow is less) >> news items.
2. Having this structure in place, write path based query so that you don't have to traverse in whole content hierarchy.
3. There is a concept of transient node in CQ, for each news item which is getting created in CQ, update the transient node with newly created item. Means for recent news you don't have to traverse content structure just refer to transient node which has reference to newly created news item.
4. You could also write a cron job which gets executed in background and takes care of collating views namely top recent news.

Comment: Thanks Rupesh. Some of my thoughts and queries. 1)The site initially will have less than 100 articles, but will only grow. Will ensure to leverage aem's content driven hierarchy. 2) Have used tagmanager.find() with base path in the arg to restrict search to particular /content level 3) Can you point to some api references if any for this. Are you referring to the state before for example session.save() is invoked? How do I access the transient node? 4) How can I use the scheduler to build a cache object that serves the recent articles result, say for 1 hour and rebuild the cache.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer of Rupesh I would say that definitely use dispatcher cache as much as you can and for using local caching strategies in AEM try using [guava](https://github.com/google/guava) cache it is a very good and easy to use tool there is also a lot of information on how you can set it up and use it for your specific needs. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. For recent news/events, write a scheduler 
   (https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scheduler-service-commons-scheduler.html) that will compute the list of recent news/events and write it to a specific node as properties, example:

/tmp/recent

- news [/path/to/news1,/path/to/news2]
- events [/path/to/event1,/path/to/event2]

Most recent always at the end of the array. Your code need to limit it to the amount of max recent you want to have.
Let's say you want to have the last 5 changed and a 6th page is changed, then you just pop and push(new_page_path)

This could run once a day or at the frequency which you feel is the best depending on your requirements.

If you need instant update, then you can additionally write a Listener when a page is changed/deleted and update the recent list. In this case I would suggest putting the code that deal with updating the recent list into a service and use that service in both the scheduler and the listener.

Listener and scheduler need to run on both author and publisher and on publisher trigger dispatcher cache invalidation for /tmp/recent afterwards.

In order to render the recent list without having to invalidate the whole pages, I would suggest you use SSI for that, that means have a component in your page that will render an SSI include to /tmp/recent.news.html or /tmp/recent.events.html depending on whether you want to render recent news or events.
Give the node /tmp/recent the resourceType for handling the "news" and "events" selector and implement that resourceType to render the content.

2. For the related
   Use the Tag Manager (https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/TagManager.html) "find" method to lookup for all news/events having the same tag as the current page. I assume your news and events pages have a dedicated template or resource type.

Also I would suggest having a dedicated component that would include that content using SSI include. Let's say your page has 2 tags, ns/tag1 and ns/tag2, then you could perform the SSI include like this:

- SSI include /etc/tags/ns/tag1.related_news.html
- SSI include /etc/tags/ns/tag1.related_events.html
- SSI include /etc/tags/ns/tag2.related_news.html
- SSI include /etc/tags/ns/tag2.related_events.html
  depending on what you want to include

Write a component under /apps/cq/tagging/components/tag (sling:resourceSuperType= /libs/cq/tagging/components/tag) that will provide the rendering for the "related_news" and "related_events" selector and list all related pages.

The advantage with this approach is that you can share the related page for each tag and whenever the tag is changed/deleted then the cache gets invalidated automatically.

In both cases (recent and related) configure the dispatcher to cache the output.